# OJDBC8 SQLFeatureNotSupportedException on getParameterMetaData

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("connectionstring","user","password");

    con.prepareStatement("UPDATE TESTTABLE SET TMPSTMPCOLUMN = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE CHARCOLUMN = ?").getParameterMetaData().getParameterClassName(1);


    return;
}
```

Executing this throws me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Nicht unterstützte Funktion: checkValidIndex
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.checkValidIndex(OracleParameterMetaData.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.getParameterClassName(OracleParameterMetaData.java:366)
    at test.main(test.java:14)
```

It seems like the Oracle JDBC driver fails to correctly parse the statement because of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Executing this Preparedstatement works but getting any metadata on the parameters doesnt as long as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is somewhere in the query.

Edit: The Driver Version is 19.3.0.0

Comment: The Oracle driver simply doesn't support `getParameterMetaData()`

Comment: I dont think so because it works without CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or simmilar clauses. I debugged into the driver and saw that he parses the query incorrectly and then returns a ParameterMetaData object with a special flag set that throws the SQLFeatureNotSupportedException upon trying to get any information out of it.

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen that work.

Comment: @MarkusShark If you already debugged your way into the code and found that it explicitly was coded to fail here, then what is your question? Actually I don't see any question in your question, so I'm going to vote to close as "**unclear what you're asking**". --- You didn't even specify which version of the driver you're using. *Hint:* The name `ojdbc8` only means that the driver is compatible with version 8 of *Java*, it doesn't say anything about the version of the *JDBC driver*.

Comment: sorry, its version 19.3.0.0